# "is not"-comparison behavior in Python

Tags: python

**Introduction**

So I'm trying to follow this tutorial on RealPython: [link](https://realpython.com/python-hash-table/#build-a-hash-table-prototype-in-python-with-tdd).
I struggle to understand the part about *defensive copying*. I've replicated the source of my confusion in my own code below.

My question is – why is the IDs different in the `a.lst_different_name is not a.lst_different_name` statement when using the same object (why does this statement evaluate to `True`)? And why is the ID altered for the same object after invoking this comparison (see output)?

**Code**

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__lst = [1, 2, 3]
    
    @property
    def lst_different_name(self):
        return self.__lst.copy()

a = TestClass()

print(a.lst_different_name)
print(id(a.lst_different_name))
print(id(a.lst_different_name))

print(a.lst_different_name is not a.lst_different_name)

print(id(a.lst_different_name))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3]
2462895845824
2462895845824
True
2462896109184
```

Comment: I think what is confusing you is the two `print` has the same value for `id()` and only after the `is not` the ID changes?

Comment: I'm getting different results - https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ciqezibohe.yaml (Python 3.9.2 on Debian). The initial ids printed are different.

Comment: You comparing the id of ephemeral objects. Python can reuse the id in these cases. The is documented behavior.

Comment: @criztovyl Correct!

Comment: @Mark it's not immediately obvious why the objects are ephemeral.  It took me at least 3 times of reading the code to see that `copy` in there.

Comment: I guess the first sentence about copying primed me to notice. But I agree @MarkRansom, this is easily overlooked on a quick scan of the problem.